# Producing isolated accents

Tags: accents

Is it possible to produce isolated accents, with no letters under it?

I'm looking for these characters in specific: ` ~ ^ ´ ˆ ˜ ¨

Comment: If you are searching for special characters, you can always look at http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Really interesting site... I'll surely bookmark it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can generate the accent like you would normally, only use a space as the letter to apply it to. As an example, consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  $\tilde{ }$ $\hat{ }$ \'{ }
\end{document}
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Accents]

Answer (score 11):

There's no need to go in math mode:

```
\`{} \'{} \^{} \~{} \v{} \u{} \.{}
```

are various examples: just tell TeX to put the accent over nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `XeLaTeX` and some individual accent characters in Greek (e.g. Psili - Unicode U+1FBF) it is posisble to ensure the character is not combined with the preceding letter using the following trick:

```
ἐπ\/᾿\ \ ὀλίγον
```

Which renders correctly as "ἐπ᾿ ὀλίγον" instead of π combined with Psili.

Comment: Note that Unicode has the non-combining psili `᾿` (U+1FBF) and also might support adding the combining accent to a non-breaking space (`^^^^00a0` or `~`)

Answer (score 0):

In Unicode, the canonical way to do this is to combine the accent with a non-breaking space (U+00A0).  In TeX, a non-breaking space is `~`,

There are also Unicode codepoints for many  non-combining accents.